# Django 3, I change DEBUG = False, and when I send letters the images disappear, why is this happening?

Tags: django

Send letters in the mail, and disappears images when DEBUG = False when DEBUG = True, everything is displayed, why is this happening ???

the website is deployed on heroku

to send emails using sendgrid

to store dynamic images using AWS

**mail template**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" >   
    <img class="img-fluid w-100" style="width: 100%;" src="sitename.com/{{ img_path }}" alt="1">
  </div>
</div>
```

**debug=true**

[image]

**debug=false**

[image]

When we upload pictures, they are uploaded to the root of the project in the media folder, what should I fix (add) so that everything works?

```
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'id_key'
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'key'
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'cinemaxpro-bucket'

    # AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Comment: Check media_root configuration. You are using aws. So also check aws access keys and  s3 bucket policy.

Comment: @PyMaster MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

Comment: @PyMaster but when the project debug = true everything works

Comment: You are storing dynamic image on aws so you have to configure your media root to store and fetch files from aws s3 bucket. So it should look like,
`MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME`

You need to configure aws storage properly for media or add your configuration here to get more help.

Comment: @PyMaster I added to the end of your configure AWS what can I add to fix this ? help please )